# How to call a function inside another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to call the function **filterElements(dataJson, btn, photographersDiv)** inside of my 2nd function **filterPhotograpsIndividualTages()** so when i click the button, my 2nd function will execute the 1st function code!

The first function **filterElements(dataJson, btn, photographersDiv)** is already being invoked somewhere else, in a on click event but I wanted to use the code of this function when I run the second function!

Any ideas of how could I do this any sources would be helpfull!

This is what I get in the console whenever I click a btn:

[image: console error]

```
// FIRST FUNCTION
function filterElements(dataJson, btn, photographersDiv){  
  dataJson.photographers.forEach(photographe => { 
    if(photographe.tags.indexOf(btn.id) != -1){
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      const photographerTemplate = `
      <div class="photographerContainer">
        <a href="photographers.html?id=${photographe.id}">
          <div class="portraitBox">
            <img src="${photographe.portrait}" alt="photo">
          </div>
          <h1 class="name">${photographe.name}</h1>
        </a>
        <p class="city">${photographe.city}, ${photographe.country}</p>
        <p class="tagline">${photographe.tagline}</p>
        <p class="price">${photographe.price}€/jour</p>
        <p class="tags">${photographe.tags.map(tag => `<button class="tag">#${tag}</button>`).join(" ")}</p>  
       </div>
      `        
      photographersDiv.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = photographerTemplate;
    }
  }); 
};

// SECOND FUNCTION
function filterPhotograpsIndividualTages() {

  const individualTags = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('individual-tags'));
  individualTags.forEach((elt, index) => elt.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    filterElements(dataJson, btn, photographersDiv);
  }))
}
```

Comment: You have to pass values to its argument, not just the values of non-existent variables which have the same name as those arguments will inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem there is that the variable "dataJson" is not within the scope of the second function. The solution there would be to pass in "dataJson" as a parameter of the second function like this:

```
filterPhotograpsIndividualTages(dataJson);
```

That way the data will be available within the scope of the second function.

**UPDATE

Here is a good resource for learning about passing parameters into functions:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

And this one will teach you about scope:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Plus you need to add the param to filterPhotograpsIndividualTages's signature

Comment: thank you very much it worked, do you have any source where I can learn more

Comment: You already know about passing data into the function because you did it with your first function. But the important thing here is scope. A variable that is declared inside of a function typically is only able to be accessed inside of that function and its nested functions. But if you declare a variable in the global or window scope (not recommended), it will generally be available to all functions.